# Is there a way to get the best of both a React project and Meteor project? Or how to just inject Meteor into a React project?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

A native React project has a lot of build features (e.g. dynamic css) that appear to get thrown away by just adding React components into a Meteor project. Is there a way to have a full-fledged React project within a Meteor project? Or is there a way to simply inject Meteor into a React project (everything seems oriented towards just injecting React components into a Meteor project), the way that there is for React-Native. The modules and documents that I've been able to find appear to be pretty outdated.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are suggesting with this.  As far as I am aware, you can still use the one feature (dynamic css) that you mention in the question;  Perhaps you should consider posting code or a [mcve] showing what you want to do and what isn't working.

Comment: Not sure what you would consider "the best of both". The [Todo App Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app) provided on meteors website is a pretty good implementation of mixing Meteor with React.

Comment: Which modules and documents are pretty outdated? As far as I see, the meteor documents are being updated fair enough.